# How to write a procedure that creates a view depending on its parameter in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I would like to write a procedure that creates a view depending on its parameter in SQL Server 2005.

Grossly, this should look like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE testprocedure
@clientid float
as
create view testview as 
select * from deliveries where clientid=@clientid
```

(but this does not work, it gives the error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'view'.)

Is it possible and how ?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to CREATE a view inside a stored proc?? 
Either you HAVE the views to select from, or you will create those manually in the SQL server and then query them..... what good can possibly come from creating a view inside a stored proc?

Comment: My more general problem is that I need to do an inner join between the result of two queries. To obtain this result, the solution I am thinking about, is storing the result of the two requests in view and then join them. I am really interested in other ideas.

Comment: @madewulf, that sounds like a regular query with a join and a WHERE clause.  post another question with what you are really trying to do...

Comment: You are right, it sounds like a join could solve this, but the problem is that ther eare group by clause involved. I will soon write a question about this.

Comment: Here is my question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300996/request-joining-the-results-of-two-other-requests-with-group-by-clause-in-sql-ser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
create procedure testprocedure
@clientid float
as
declare @query  varchar(8000)
set @query='create view testview as select * from deliveries where clientid='+CONVERT(varchar(20),@clientid)
IF  EXISTS (SELECT object_id FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('testview'))
BEGIN
    DROP VIEW testview
END
exec (@Query)

go
```

Comment: lol. i know, you beat me by exactly 3 seconds. +1 for quicker on the draw.  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that i would recommend this as a solution to any kind of problem but you could try something like this: (dynamic sql)

CREATE PROCEDURE testprocedure

@clientid float

as

DECLARE @sql varchar(8000) set @sql = ''

SET @sql = @sql + 'create view testview as  '

SET @sql = @sql + 'select * from deliveries where clientid=@clientid '

SET @sql = @sql + cast(@clientid as varchar(50))

EXEC(@sql)